# How to call another activity method in android studio?

Tags: android, android-activity, methods

I have two different activities.
The first calls the menu(base) if the user is logged in, but have also the method for display the user information.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    UserLocalStore userLocalStore;
    EditText etName, etAge, etUsername;
    Button bLogout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAge);
        bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);

        bLogout.setOnClickListener(this);

        userLocalStore = new UserLocalStore(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bLogout:
                userLocalStore.clearUserData();
                userLocalStore.setUserLoggedIn(false);
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (authenticate() == true) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Base.class));
        }
    }

    private boolean authenticate() {
        if (userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser() == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void displayUserDetails() {
        User user = userLocalStore.getLoggedInUser();
        etUsername.setText(user.username);
        etName.setText(user.name);
        etAge.setText(user.age + "");
    }
}
```

The second activity is the menu; this activity has a button called "bUtente" that when clicked must show the user info.

```
public class Base extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button bDiario;
    Button bUtente;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
        bDiario = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDiario);
        bDiario.setOnClickListener(this);
        bUtente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUtente);
        bUtente.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.bDiario:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, Diary.class));

            case R.id.bUtente:
                MainActivity prova = new MainActivity();
                prova.displayUserDetails();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that when I click the button "bUtente" reminds me of the other activity by performing the method "displayUserDetails()"?

Comment: You can either pass the info to the second activity and use it there or create a Utility class that can be accessed and display information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainActivity` has a layout that contains the `View`s that show the user information. If you are in `Base`, that Activity has a different layout that doesn't have any `View`s for showing the user information. You can create a `Dialog` that shows the user information, or you could add additional `View`s to `Base` that would show the user information, or you could rearchitect your application so that you have another `Activity` which shows the user information and both `MainActivity` and `Base` could start that `Activity` to show the user information.

In any case, you absolutely positively cannot instantiate an `Activity` like `MainActivity` using the `new` keyword! Only Android can instantiate `Activity` components, because the framework sets up the underlying `Context` when it does that. It also keeps track of these components and manages the lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: thank you, I think I will rearchitect my application