# Android calling a method from another acitivt6 from a class

Tags: android

I have an activity named Create and a class names Begin .I would like to access the methods in activity using the class begin.

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Ehtizad Zashkiyor ,

You can't really access another activity method, and the way that it is possible are not reccomanded.

it's better for you to try to make a java class with the methods you want and let both your activity get the methods form there.

from a quick search in google I found few questions that will help you:

- [how to call a method in another Activity from Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666572/how-to-call-a-method-in-another-activity-from-activity)
- [Call a public method in the Activity class from another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836415/call-a-public-method-in-the-activity-class-from-another-class)
- [How to call another activity method in android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32103547/8405296) (this one is straight to the answer of it)

plus, it wont hurt you to read this: "[Application Fundamentals](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html)" which is from the [android developer](https://developer.android.com/) website.

I hope this answers to your question, if you'll have any further concerns, don't be shy and ask.